# Nesting existing textfield view in a new view

Tags: ember.js

I have been getting a bit stuck in finding a way to reuse an ember textfield so any help would be appreciated.

What I have is (simplified here) a selection of rows like:

```
<div class="detailItem">Email: {{view Ember.TextField  valueBinding="email"}} </div>
<div class="detailItem">Name: {{view Ember.TextField  valueBinding="name"}} </div>
```

and instead of always wrapping in a div I'd like to make use of a new view. e.g.:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="detailItem">   
<div class="detailItem">{{Item name}}: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="itemValue"}} </div>
</script>

App.DetailItemView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'detailItem',
    name: "",
        ......
});
```

The thing I am not sure is how I get the textfield's valueBinding to link up to my controller (well actually it's content). I can obviously add another property to DetailItemView and instantiate it with that property having the values 'email' and 'name'. How though would I then pass these into the contained Ember.TextField?

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
App.DetailItemView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'detail_item',
  classNames: ['detailItem'],
  label: null,
  value: ''
});
```

and the template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="detail_item">
  {{view.label}}: 
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="view.value"}}
</script>
```

And then use it like this:

```
{{view App.DetailItemView label="Email" valueBinding="email"}}
{{view App.DetailItemView label="Name" valueBinding="name"}}
```

Comment: Thanks I actually had done something similar earlier today but it didn't work. Think it must have just been a type or missing "". Much appreciated

Comment: Do you mind trying it and confirm it worked for other people reading this question later on?